# Is there terminology for perceptual illusions at the moment that figure-ground reversal occurs?

Tags: perception, vision, visualization

I'm looking for a term in the perception / cognition area of research.

I recently saw [this visual illusion](https://i.imgur.com/eXr9rNa.gifv) that 'flips' what is *negative-space* and what is *positive-space*.  This is known in the arts as "[figure-ground reversal](https://www.google.com/search?q=figure-ground%20reversal)"

I am looking for a word / term that addresses when the thing we are observing changes, such that the parts that signify the 'figure' and 'ground' are themselves switched.  Is there a word for this?  Does Ecological Psychology have a way that it organizes such stimuli?

[image]

I would think there may be a term that address when our perception 'flips' the perception of [a static image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Cup_or_faces_paradox.svg/300px-Cup_or_faces_paradox.svg.png), and afterward we are biased to perceive the 'ground' differently.  This happens when we see a *vase* instead of *faces*.

But I don't know *that word*, nor do I know if it applies to the occurrence of when a thing/image/perceptual-field changes, in order to *action* the figure-ground reversal.

[image]

Comment: I would call it Perceptual switches. Here's one example where the term is used: http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2288056. Switch rate usually describes the mean time a given percept is dominant.

Answer (score 2):

There are many such illusions. It mostly belongs to pattern-recognition and gestalt psychology. From German it means *"shape", "form", "essence"*. To answer your question, I think, here there are *illusory contours* (when you watch and understand an illusion) and *lateral inhibition* (when you have got new understanding of the picture and compare it with previous form).

Enjoy more pictures ;)

[image: A man and a woman face]
[image: A joke about gestalt-psychologists]

Comment: Nice thought. I wonder if this is a kind of *"lateral inhibition hysteresis"*?